# 100% Height on iOS device not working

Tags: html, ios, css, height

I draw a vertical line in html like this:

```css
.vr-long {
  background: #000000;
  border: none;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<hr class="vr-long">
```

This works fine on every device (PC, Android) and every tested browser except all browsers on my ipad (iphone not tested). On my ipad all vertical lines dissappeared. The problem seems to be the "height: 100%;" because when I use `height: 50px;` for example, I get that vertical line.

Any ideas how to get `height: 100%` to work on iOS?

By the way: Same problem when I use an img-tag to draw a vertical line by using repeat-y and height: 100% ...

Comment: I cant see your line in example, because you need to set for body and html also height 100%. Try to set `height: 100vh` instead of 100%. If that works - you need to check all parents of your `vr-long` and set them height: 100%

Comment: height:100vh works, but i've set the parents already to height:100%. Like I said, the vertical lines appear on every device except iOS...

Comment: This code doesn't replicate the issue ..... so it's impossible to test

Comment: They don't appear on my MacBook Pro either.

Comment: Yeah, I'd wonder if 100vh like at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26145975/470749 helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a div as a vertical lign.

```css
.vr-long {
  margin: 0 2em 0 2em;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="vr-long"></div>
```

I still dont't know why the problem only appeared on my ipad, but that workaorund doesn't cause any problems.