# Close menu on outside click doesn't work only in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function closeMenu() {
 $('.list-item').removeClass('activeItem');
 $('.showSubMenu').removeClass('showSubMenu');
 $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
 $('#burger').removeClass('change');
 });

$('html').on('click', function(e) {
      closeMenu(); 
 });

 $('.list-item, .showSubMenu, #burger, #menuToggle').click( function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

This JS works and closes responsive menu on outside click in Chrome (desktop and mobile) and Safari (desktop-only), but not Firefox!?? What's wrong? Syntax error? Any wisdom is much appreciated.

See full code in action here:(Working in Chrome and Safari desktop):
http://cardscreative.com/cc2017/test444.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `body` is only taking up the portion where your search bar is in Mozilla, so if you click anywhere else it doesn't register as having clicked on the `body`. If you set the `body` to `height: 100%` it appears to work.

Comment: Tried your solution first and it worked... and was more simple. But, it still doesn't work in safari mobile version of ios? Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144773/height-100-on-html-body-is-not-working-on-iphone) says that `vh` should be supported in Safari Mobile, which corresponds to the height of the viewport and would be functionally equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).on('click','body *',function(){
         closeMenu(); 
});
```

Comment: Tried css height:100%; solution below first, and it worked, but I changed the function to yours above anyway, as it seemed more all-inclusive. Removing height:100%; broke it again.  Next issue is that it still doesn't work on safari mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JavaScript for the example site you posted, (http://cardscreative.com/cc2017/test444.js), there's the following code:

`$(document.body).on('click', function(e) {
...
}`

For Firefox, the document body only takes up the full height of its content, not the full height of the window. So, this function does not get attached to click events which happen outside the content `<body>`. In your example site, the content body consists of the navigation bar.

This issue can be fixed with the following change:

`$(document).on('click', ...`

This change will attach the function to all clicks in the document, not just the body.

(Also, your question says `$('html').on('click', ...`. You should update your question to reflect the JavaScript of the site.)